# AWS - EC2, AWS Batch - best solution to computing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-batch

I need to do some computing in AWS once a month for 10-15 hours.
If I wanted to choose EC2, I calculated that probably I need to Instance Type - P2, xlarge. But I need to do this computing only once a month, so maybe this is overkill and I tried to find a better solution.
And I heard about AWS Batch, I read about it, and looks good.
But, do you have any suggestions on what can I use? Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: What do you want to optimize for? There is no "best", there are only trade offs.

Comment: *Better solution* depends on more detailed requirements (functional or not). There are multiple options. When having an on-demand task running for 15h to process, the AWS Batch could be feasible (good enough)

Comment: @Maurice You're right. I want to optimize costs (money).

Comment: "I need to do this computing only once a month, so maybe this is overkill" => When you use EC2, you only pay for the time the machine is running. For this you need to make sure you terminate it after the computation, e.g. by wrapping it in a docker and running it using AWS Batch.

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 0):

Batch is an orchestration service.

It will use the p2.xlarge instances under the hood if that is what your application needs. You should also look at the G4 and G5 instances. Nice thing about Batch is that you can just set it up once and then send the request whenever you need to and Batch will handle launching the instance(s) for you.

If you can checkpoint your 15 hour processes (save data and recover the job at the point it died) you can leverage Spot for saving on-demand cost. Today Spot price for p2.xlarge is $0.27/hour in US-East 1 https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/